# Is it possible to design reports using SSRS on dimensional database_

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

We have Sql server database and it is designed on snow flakes (Facts and Dimensions) schema. These tables don't have PK and FK relationship. Instead we are maintaining these information in metadata tables.

Is it possible to design reports in SSRS on these tables?

I want to design reports by combining different columns from tables.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the Fact and Dimension tables are held in a conventional relational database, you can access them in SSRS using conventional SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

If the database structure is OLAP, you'll need MDX to query instead of T-SQL

Answer (score 0):

yes, of courser you can!
It doesn't matter how your data is structured on your database, if you manage to build a query to display it, SSRS will be able to read it on a DataSet and use it on the report

Answer (score 0):

A SELECT statement is sufficient.  A view or a stored proc are preferred.  It's hard to imagine a SQL database that doesn't support those options.